# What security threats do tradesmen face in their use of IT?

Tags: vulnerability, defense, risk-management, countermeasure

I'm designing a system for tradesmen and doing research into the security issues. I have the basics covered and am now looking for more specific threats.

What threats or vulnerabilities may be specific to tradesmen or may tradesmen be more at risk from?

Comment: Getting _over-charged_ on transactions? [Short-circuit SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)?

Comment: Do you mean like electric plants, generation systems and such? Or the electricians themselves, in the typical everyday work they do for their customers?

Comment: I'm afraid this is getting low views because nobody on this site is very familiar with the details of the electrical profession. Could you provide examples of the kinds of IT use cases that are specific to that profession?

Comment: This is a tough question then; most electricians aren't experts in identifying security risks, and most security experts aren't aware of the ins and outs of an electrician's job. I think the quality of answer you'll get will depend on how much detail you can give us about the kinds of things electricians typically use technology for (in particular, think about sensitive information that they handle either about themselves or about their customers, and how this is stored and transmitted). Feel free to [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/143070/edit) your question.

Comment: Or are you thinking of just a generic service professional, making rounds of house calls? As far as that goes, I don't think there is typically much that would be specific to electricians only...

Comment: It's becoming more likely for electricians to install network devices without IT knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[This is a very general answer, pending more detail in the question]*

---

So you're asking for help doing a security risk assessment specific to the electrician profession. I'm no expert in electrical work, but here's some things off the top of my head to get you thinking in the right direction, not by any means exhaustive:

Physical security

- Leaving their truck unattended in odd locations.
- Entering unknown homes / buildings
- Connecting their equiment to potentially malicious / malwary circiuts? (seems low risk, I'm scraping the bottom here...)

Information security

- Make a list of sensitive information they handle and classify how sensitive it is, ex.:

  - Schedule of where they will be at a given time [medium]
  - Customer addresses [low]
  - Customer billing information, possibly including credit card numbers [high]
  - Alarm codes or key locations to enter a customer's home or building [High]
  - Diagrams or schematics of customer buildings [high]
  - etc
- Make a list of ways this information is stored:

  - Paper
  - On phone (in sms)
  - On phone (in company app)
  - On Laptop (in Word documents)
  - On Laptop (in login-protected web site)
  - etc
- Make a list of ways this information could be stolen, copied, or tampered with, and assess its risk:

  - Paper left in truck
  - Clipboard left on table while they poke their head into something
  - Phone stolen (phone encrypted and password protected?)
  - Laptop stolen (laptop encrypted and password protected?)
  - Connection between laptop and server intercepted (using `https`?)
  - Customer shoulder-surfs info they shouldn't see from phone / laptop screen (including passwords, which raises the risk of phone / laptop theft).
  - etc